# How do I get weight sensor's data to Raspberry Pi (HX711 Load cell)?

Tags: python

Can someone please give me the Python code to get the weight from a HX711 load cell into the Raspberry Pi?

Also, can you please let me know if you used an I2C or SPI protocol?

Comment: No website had the code for it.

Comment: Have you seen this http://hivetool.org/w/index.php?title=Interface_the_HX711_to_Pi or https://github.com/ggurov/hx711

Comment: Check this repo: https://github.com/tatobari/hx711py A few months ago I found [this repo](https://gist.github.com/underdoeg/98a38b54f889fce2b237) and decided to make a few modifications I needed. Since I didn't get any answers from the owner I made my own repo and credited the guy. It has can definitely be improved but it works.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOpkIdKbiDY
this video will help you,
connecting raspberry pi and loadcell

Comment: Here is my open source implementation in python 3 and 2.7
I provide examples.
Check my git: https://github.com/gandalf15/HX711
No i2c or SPI needed. It is just bit banging.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the SparkFun website.  They have a scale board already created based on the HX711 that is fully functional with the raspberry pi and a PC if you wish.  They have code for the board and it is low cost as well.  I have used this board to integrate industrial scales into a raspberry pi and works great.

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13261